# combine two tables into one result set sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dataset, pivot-table, reportbuilder3.0

I have a stored procedure that is deserializing an XML string and adding it to a table in the form of;

```
MonthDate        floatValue
01/01/2014       10,123.23
02/03/2014       11,324.34
```

and so on.
I then have a set of simulated results that i need to correspond to those dates, but they are in a comma delimited dataset that is formed like this;

```
[123.43,125.34,134.33],[124.33,143.33,234.22],etc..
```

I have written a function that parses out the string into a table of 1 column and groupIDs of that data that looks like this;

```
tempID        floatValue
1             123.43
1             125.34
1             134.33
2             124.33
2             143.33
2             234.22
```

I have tried using pivot tables on this second set of data, but the aggregation ruins the datasets since I have to have them in their specific order to correlate with the dates in my first deserialized XML result.  Basically what I want for a result is something that would be like;

```
MonthDate     MedianResult    temp1    temp2    etc..
01/01/2014    10,123.23       123.43   124.33
02/03/2014    11,324.34       125.34   143.33
```

That's really the best I can explain it, i have the queries written to get the result sets that i've shown but have no idea how to "combine" two tables to get what im looking for.

Comment: the function that parses out the string into a table of 1 column and and groupIDs, could it be amended to add a sequence ID 1,2,3 to ensure proper order is applied to the float values or will the float value always be lowest to highest?  If you do add 1,2,3 a case statement could get you the desired results using the 1,2,3; otherwise you have to use a pseudo or temp value to maintain order; and a select can't guarantee the same order as the insert... so knowing specific order, or that it's always from lowest to highest helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a partitioned id and pivoting from there?  Granted, this example will sort the values ascending but conceptually, its a start?

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [tempID] ORDER BY [floatValue]) AS [RowNumber]
```

Comment: I decided to take a different route than using a pivot table.  Since i am dynamically creating both tables to merge, I decided to use an auto-increment identity on the original MonthDate table and create a separate ID row that increments through the total number of rows per tempID.  that way each tempID (2-12) will also have an ID column between 1 and 113 (or more) that matches the date identity exactly.  I am then just joining the tables on the ID and it works great.